# Can I still see someone in my chat list if they removed

Tags: facebook

If someone removes me from their friend list, can I still be able to see their name and photo in my chat list?

Comment: Clear and your caches and refresh the page using CTRL+F5 to see the changes.

Answer (score 1):

If they unfriend you on Facebook they are no longer a friend and therefore will not appear in your list of friends to chat with. You will still be able to send them messages though, just they will not appear on the bar on the right. Of course if they blocked you, you will also not be able to send them any messages.